# Cannot execute a procedure through C# in MySql commercial edition

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I recently have an upgrade of server. It also included migration of MySQL from community edition to MySQL commercial edition. Now, I can not seem to execute the procedure through a c# desktop application which has been working fine for months. It gives me the following error:

> Unable to retrieve stored procedure metadata for routine '{0}'. 
>   Either grant  SELECT privilege to mysql.proc for this user or use "use
>   procedure bodies=false" with  your connection string.

I have checked the rights for the user I am using at back end and it has all the sufficient rights. I am guessing I am missing the difference between either the connector or the connection string building between MySQL editions.Could someone please guide me?

**UPDATE:**

I checked if `SELECT` statements are running. And I found out that they are in fact being executed. with the same connection string (which contradicts the exception shared above).Also,the only difference between `SELECT` statement and calling the procedure is that I am creating the raw query in the aplpication and then using `ExecuteScalar` where as for stored procedure I am using `ExecuteNonQuery`.